# How to add a validated number to sinch sandbox

Tags: python, sms, sinch

I am currently leveraging Sinch SMS to send SMS notifications based on events for a web application in python using sinchsms.  When I send a message I get this exception:

```
HTTP Error 403: Sandobx SMS only allowed to be sent to verified numbers.
```

With this stacktrace:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sinchsms.py", line 79, in send_message
    return self._request(self.SEND_SMS_URL + to_number, values)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sinchsms.py", line 40, in _request
    connection = urllib2.urlopen(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 437, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 550, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 475, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 558, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Sandobx SMS only allowed to be sent to verified numbers.
```

I don't see a way on the sinch sms dashboard to validate the number or register a number

Answer (score 2):

In sandbox mode you can send sms to one number only (an unfortunate side effect of some scammers/fraudsters). You can verify you number under https://www.sinch.com/dashboard/#/account.   To send to any number, you need to make a payment and request a production key.

Comment: Can you clarify on "You can verify you number under ..." I"m not sure what you mean exactly, you mean adding the company number?

Comment: under https://www.sinch.com/dashboard/#/account you should see a text verify phonenumber