# How to add numbers to sinch sandbox?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, sinch

I want to add another number in my `sinch` sandbox account.

When I tried with another number to send an SMS I got the below response.

```
{
    "errorCode":40303,
    "message":"Sandbox SMS only allowed to be sent to verified numbers.",
    "reference":"A:1caa68ca-7189-4cb6-a7a1-917f71a9ec1c_2+GvK+E5zUqGYzztGZJ/GA"
}
```

How can I add other numbers in `sinch` sandbox account?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a validated number to sinch sandbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30468789/how-to-add-a-validated-number-to-sinch-sandbox)

Comment: we can not add another number to sinch sanbox account?